# How to use Google Maps with a local GeoRSS file?

Tags: google-maps

How can I get Google maps to use a local GeoRSS file for a marker layer instead of having it reformed on the Google servers into a Kml layer object and having it poll the server for every popup.

I'm fairly certain the previous version of the API did what I want it to do, and they changed it for the most recent version. How, if at all, can I change it back?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put it on Google servers, but you can host it on your own site and view GeoRSS simply by pasting the URL in the search box of maps.google.com

Comment: The problem is that Google doesn't have a path to my internal network address. It's not routed that way (on purpose).

Comment: The point is, you'll need to put it on a public server, if you want it view on maps.google.com

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. I knew I didn't have to actively host the data on google's servers full-time, but the fact that all parsing has to go _through_ their servers doesn't meet my business needs, ya know?

Comment: Understood. But realizing that it has to be parsed somewhere, it makes sense that it is parsed on the client (Google Maps), which displays the info.

Comment: I don't think that you and I use the same terms here. The client to me is the browser. OpenLayers and the older Bing Maps (ala Microsoft Virtual Earth for the browser via javascript) both do this processing in the client. The latest Bing Maps API that just came out I haven't personally looked at (but someone told me there was a later one). But in this case, the processing of the GeoRSS feed on the Google layer is processed at the server, not in the browser. So it is not processed by the client, it is processed by Google.

Comment: Right, I wasn't using the term client in the same way. It is done server side on Google Maps